# Gnuplot set terminal canvas and output as a html file

Tags: html, canvas, terminal, gnuplot

Can someone show me an example of setting canvas terminal and generating output as a html file that can be viewed on browser? Something like:

```
.....
set terminal canvas
set output 'output.html'
.....
```

Could you give me a COMMAND EXAMPLE of a simple plot (say histogram) which is generated as a html output file via the canvas terminal.

Could someone advise me on this?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
gnuplot> set terminal canvas
Terminal type set to 'canvas'
Options are ' solid butt size 600,400 fsize 10 lw 1 fontscale 1 standalone'
gnuplot> set output 'output.html'  
gnuplot> plot [0:25] sin(x)
```

worked for me. Is your problem that you don't get output, or that you don't know the commands to plot a histogram?

If you don't get output, 'pwd' will tell you the directory your file is in.

If setting your terminal to canvas doesn't work, you may be using too old a version of gnuplot.

If you don't know how to plot a histogram,  [this](http://skuld.bmsc.washington.edu/~merritt/gnuplot/canvas_demos/histograms.html) is a good place to start, and if you still have questions, you should ask specifically about that.